# I would like to use AutoCompleteTextBox to replicate the new tags textbox used in Delicious, where can I find helpful examples?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, autocomplete, event-handling

I am currently developing a WPF C# application where users can plan and analyse their personal finance.

I am making use of the WPF AutoCompleteTextBox and would like users to capture tags to describe the transaction separated by a delimiter such as a comma, similar to how the [delicious](http://delicious.com) bookmarking service is doing it.

I am still a novice programmer.

Any guidance, suggestions, information, references, examples would really help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at this control: http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/WPFAutoCompleteBox/